# if there's no super object created,why can I call the super constructor in java

Tags: java

if there's no super object created when creating a new sub-class object,why can I call the super constructor in the sub-class constructor & pass to it parameters in java?

Comment: A subclass object is-a superclass object, so from that point of view a superclass object _is_ created.

Comment: each class incorporates its superclasses (parents),

Comment: A constructor does not create an object.  A construct merely initializes the state of the object, as part of the object creation process.  A subclass’s constructor initializes the state of that subclass.  Each superclass’s constructor has the job of initializing any state held in that superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an instance of a subclass JVM creates instances of all superclasses (including `Object`). If you don't call constructor of parent class yourself JVM will do it for you if parent class has noarg constructor or you will have a compilation error if your parent class doesn't have noarg constructor and you don't call any other patent class constructors yourself.

Comment: no,i'm sure that is not the case

Comment: @bakedchocolatechip Well you are wrong, because it most certainly is the case.

Comment: Super object **is** created every time you create a child class object. Just check java language specification

Comment: it does not create intances of all superclasses, this are part of each *subclass* e.g. an instance of `String` is also an instance of `Object`(augmented by the `String` methods, fields, functionality) - so, the parent class (and all its parents) is part of the subclass

Comment: @bakedchocolatechip can we know where you heard that from?

Comment: so you're saying that there's a super-class object created,but it is not separated from the sub-class object?

Comment: @Andy turner,geeks4geeks

Comment: @bakedchocolatechip where did you got your information? I got my information, among **others**, from [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/index.html), the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/index.html) and the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) (and a *bit* of experience)

Comment: @Carlos_heuberger,I've got it from geeks4geeks,however I believe java language specification are more official source,just to make sure,the answer is there is a super-class object created but it is not separated from the sub-class object?

Comment: @bakedchocolatechip are you speaking about this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-52-java-object-creation-of-inherited-classes ? Even code in that article shows that constructor of parent class is executed. Maybe wording in my answer a  it misleading, there will be no separate object in memory for parent class instance. There will be a location in memory for child object instance that has fields of parent class initialized by parent constructor and on top of that field of child class initialized by child constructor

Comment: again there is no additional super-class instance, the sub-class instance includes its parents (and grndparents) (if a `Car` extends a `Vehicle` then an instance of `Car` also includes the fields, methods, ... of `Vehicle`)

Comment: the very start of that article says: "*In inheritance, subclass acquires super class properties. An **important point** to note is, when subclass object is created, a separate **object of super class** object will **not be created**. Only a subclass object object is created that has super class variables.*"

Comment: @lvan,yes,i'm sorry but that is new to me & it makes a bit of confusion I say,thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You execute super constructor in order to execute the code which might be setting object's properties inherited from the super class.

Comment: you sure that is it?